# Rsync with SSH prompting for remote password

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, passwords, rsync

I have followed [the following guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/) to setup Rsync with SSH between my local machine and a remote server:

I performed the below as root:

1. `rsync -avz -e ssh /home/user/dir root@192.168.200.10::Backup/dir` -> prompts for password
2. `ssh-keygen` -> Key generated
3. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 192.168.200.10` -> confirmation that keys were copied
4. `ssh 192.168.200.10` -> Accesses the remote server without promting for password
5. `rsync -avz -e ssh /home/user/dir root@192.168.200.10::Backup/dir` -> Prompts for password

Is it not strange that I can SSH into the remote server without being prompted for the password but do when using rsync?

I can see `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you ssh to the remote server are you doing it as root ?

Comment: Yes I ssh as root. I had tried the same steps as user but am prompted for password when I ssh

Comment: the following isn't the cause of the problem but just a point.. I think with the -i  you should remove `.pub` because -i specifies the private key, and you can remove `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` completely because that's the default afaik. (unless you set a different default), but even then you don't want .pub after the -i  but that's not the erason for your problem since you say ssh is working fine, it's rsync that isn't.

Comment: @ChinaDiapers For those who do not want to use the daemon mode, and have an alternate port in use and/or store their `id_rsa.pub` in a separate location, I left some examples below.  Moreover, even without alternate port and in the standard location, I cannot get the officially accepted answer to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing two separate connection modes: with a remote shell (`-e ssh`) and without a remote shell, thru a `rsync daemon` (identified by the double colon).

[The manual](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html) states:

> **CONNECTING TO AN RSYNC SERVER**
>
> It  is  also possible to use rsync without a remote shell as the trans-
>          port. In this case you will connect to a remote rsync server running on
>          TCP port 873.
>
> ......
>   you  either  use  a double colon :: instead of a single colon to
>                 separate the hostname from the path, or you use an rsync:// URL.
>
> .......
>   Some paths on the remote server may require authentication. If so  then
>          you  will receive a password prompt when you connect. You can avoid the
>          password prompt by setting the environment variable  RSYNC_PASSWORD  to
>          the  password you want to use or using the --password-file option. This
>          may be useful when scripting rsync.

Probably the simplest way to obtain passwordless authentication for you is to modify the command above as follows:

```
   rsync -avz -e ssh /home/user/dir root@192.168.200.10:/absolute/path/to/Backup/dir
```

Comment: Yes mate, that was it. I must have added the colon in one of my many experiments in trying to get this working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your username on your local account is probably not `root`, which is the username you use with Rsync.

```
ssh remotehost
```

…is effectively the same as:

```
ssh localUserName@remotehost
```

---

Sorry, I didn't notice that you already said you’re running as root.

I also didn’t notice that you are using the module syntax with two colons (`::`) after the remote hostname. I don’t think [the guide you followed](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rsync-over-ssh-without-password/) covers connecting to Rsync this way, and that you should be fine if you use the single colon syntax, for example:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh /home/user/dir root@192.168.200.10:/some/path/backups/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too - I hope this helps. For me, the problem was the syntax required for alternate port ssh.  Here are two working examples:

Execute this from the target backup machine, which pulls from source to target backup:

`rsync -av --delete -e 'ssh -p 59333 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' user@10.9.9.3:/home/user/Server/ /home/user/Server/`

Execute this from the source machine, which sends from source to target backup:

`rsync -av --delete -e 'ssh -p 59333 -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' /home/user/Server/ user@10.9.9.3:/home/user/Server/`

This solution assumes you already exchanged your public key with target and/or vice versa using `ssh-copy-id -p 59333`.  This wonky syntax is not required if you use port 22, in which case you can use the `i` flag and it will procure the public key from the default location in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.  Here is an example without alternate port that also works fine:

Execute this from the target backup machine, which pulls from source to target backup:

`sudo rsync -avi --delete  user@10.9.9.3:/var/www/ /media/sdb1/backups/www/`

Execute this from the source machine, which sends from source to target backup:

`sudo rsync -avi --delete /media/sdb1/backups/www/ user@10.9.9.3:/var/www/`

If you are still getting prompted for a password, then you need to check your ssh configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and verify that the users in source and target each have the others' respective public ssh key.  I left this amount of detail because the syntax left by two others above still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I always log in with my p[rivate key and connect to the server where my authorized_key is

like this

```bash
/usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete  -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/marcel_id_rsa" root@localhost:/opt/ /backup/1-Zondag
```

It works from the cron..  nu passwd asked

If this is not working because the remote server refuses... this works for sure

sshpass -p "mypassword" /usr/bin/rsync -avz --delete  -e ssh root@localhost:/opt/ /backup/1-Zondag